# Object Retrieved From Database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When retrieve a record from database , it retrieve object, but How to know is a Empty Object which no data retrieved ...

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#243 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

this is empty object retrieved from database .. How to check if this Empty or Not ... via PHP methods or something like that !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check using `Collection::count()` method:

```
if($collectionObject->count()) {
    // has data/records
}
```

For opposite:

```
if(!$collectionObject->count()) {
    // 0 records returned
}
```

Comment: Haha, we meet again! Was about to answer this as well :) Another way would be to use if($object->isEmpty()) {}